# How is Attributes protected and yet can still be set?

Tags: function-construction, attributes

The `Attributes` function itself has the attributes:

```
Attributes[Attributes]
```

> ```
> {HoldAll,Listable,Protected}
> ```

In particular, it is `Protected` which prevents me from redefining it:

```
Attributes = Foo
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[2]:= Set::wrsym: Symbol Attributes is Protected. >>
>
> Foo
> ```

however, I am able to modify `Attributes` if I associate to a symbol:

```
Attributes[Foo] = {Protected}
```

> ```
> {Protected}
> ```

which seems strange to me, because other functions which are `Protected` can't do this.  For example, with this newly protected `Foo` function, the following fails:

```
Foo[a] = 5
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[5]:= Set::write: Tag Foo in Foo(a) is Protected. >>
>
>  5
> ```

So how does the `Protected` attribute really work, and what makes the situation with the `Attributes` function different from my simple `Foo` function?  Is it possible to have `Foo` work in the same way as `Attributes`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `Attributes` have `UpValues`(*) associated with them so at the end you are not trying to `Set` to `Attributes[Foo]` but it will be translated.

You can mimic that with e.g. `UpSetDelayed (^:=)`:

```
ClearAll[f]

Set[f[x_], attr_] ^:= SetAttributes[x, attr];

SetAttributes[f, {Protected, HoldFirst}]
```

---

```
f = 2
```

> ```
> Set::wrsym: Symbol f is Protected. >>
> ```

```
f[x] = HoldFirst (*no error*)

Attributes[x]
```

> ```
> {HoldFirst}
> ```

---

(*) Though I'm not sure if that is indeed the functionality used since   `` <<GeneralUtilities` `` and `PrintDefinitions @ Attributes` shows something like `_[___, Attributes, ___] := <<kernel function>>;`. It's probably done in a slightly different way, not accesible to user(?), but I believe my point is valid.

Comment: Thanks for that!  I originally figured it could be to do with `Set`, but I had no idea that it could be used in this way.